# What is the derivative of $z^z$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$z$ is a complex quantity, I assumed $z$ as $r\exp(i\theta)$ and proved the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Then wrote the derivative of $z^z$ as $\exp(-i\theta)(u_r+i{v_r})$.didn't know how to continue after here to prove it as $z^z(1+log(z)$

$u_r$ is the partial derivative of $u$, the real part of $z^z$ and likewise with $v$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(z) = z^z$, then $\log f(z) = z \log z$, so differentiating implicitly with respect to $z$ yields: $$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = 1 + \log z.$$ Multiplying through by $f(z)$ yields $$f'(z) = z^z(1 + \log z).$$

Comment: The question asks us to use the cr equations.

Comment: Was I supposed to read your mind?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was implied when I said I proved the cr equations. I'm aa first timer here

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Use [**logarithmic differentiation**](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/taking-derivatives/derivatives-inverse-functions/e/logarithmic-differentiation).

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The question asks us to use the cr equations